# Creating conditional flows using Jenkin's Build Flow Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using Jenkins for automated mobile device testing. However, sometimes the devices cannot be connected to and time is wasted running useless tests. To remedy this, we have instituted a connection check that only runs the test flow if a simple test can pass first.

Currently, this set up requires us to use 2 VMs, one to run the test and one to build the first and then wait around until its done to run the condition (we can't downstream for other reasons).

This is a pretty big resource hog, so I wanted to change the condition handling to the jenkins flow using the Build-Flow Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

Does the plug-in handle conditionals as below? If so, what would be the correct syntax for the conditional statement?

```
build("Connection-check")

if(Connection-check.lastBuild == Pass) //Guessed Pseudo-expression
    {build("Rest-of-Tests")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in the end I constructed a secondary flow that ran first, and only kicked off the main flow if a connection could be made using the standard conditional tools.

A little bit less compact than I would have liked, but at the least it was clear as to what it did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition:

```
if(hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("Connection-check").getLastBuild().result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
{
    build("Rest-of-Tests")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use also something like that:

```
import hudson.model.*
def connCheck = build("Connection-check") //Returns hudson.model.AbstractBuild
if(connCheck.result == Result.SUCCESS) {
   ...
}
```